# XCode: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, linker-errors

I am working on a project, and when I build the project, I got an issue which is the following:

```
Ld /Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Products/Debug/SpaceInvaders.app/Contents/MacOS/SpaceInvaders normal x86_64
    cd /Users/KiKo-SaMa/Desktop/SpaceInvaders
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Intermediates/SpaceInvaders.build/Debug/SpaceInvaders.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SpaceInvaders.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Cocoa -o /Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Products/Debug/SpaceInvaders.app/Contents/MacOS/SpaceInvaders

duplicate symbol _Cycles in:
    /Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Intermediates/SpaceInvaders.build/Debug/SpaceInvaders.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/emulator.o
    /Users/KiKo-SaMa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceInvaders-cgcsumybmrxbddfqdwhevdvubdic/Build/Intermediates/SpaceInvaders.build/Debug/SpaceInvaders.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SpaceInvadersMachine.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

At first, I looked at the questions here and tried to understand the error message, it seemed I had a duplicate variable name, so I changed it and when I try to build it again, I keep getting the same error, I checked also for duplicate function names, nothing seems to be wrong with my code. I also checked for the includes, because in a question, one of the solutions was including .m instead of .h. Can someone please help me with this.

I don't know if this is relevant, but at first I got 3 issues, it seemed I had to add to the "Compile Sources" of the "Build Phases" of my project two C files, and now I only get 1 issue which is the above one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to Organizer(top right), Projects , Select project (left column) , Delete derived data
If this doesnt do the trick...then :
Check every file(even header files) for  : Cycle
You will find it in two files...delete it from one file...you are good to go

Comment: The organizer idea didnt work, and I checked all files again, and I only have it in 2 files emulator.h which has the array itself called Cycles, and emulator.c where I return an element from the array in a function

Comment: The error implies that you have declared Cycles in two files(not just using it).I ve seen this error and that was exactly what i was doing.Try exiting Xcode.Last chance....create new project and copy/paste things one bye one to make sure Cycles is declared only once.Sorry no other ideas.

Comment: I dont know if this is relevant also, but in the other file where I used it, i changed it to DoCPUCycles, does that mean I should change it completely different from the word Cycles or it doesn't matter?

Comment: You created new variable with name DoCPUCycles? if so....no problem.Check SpaceInvadersMachine files!You have some with this name right??In there there must be the second declaration

Comment: I tried to copy everything into a new project and it worked. It built with no error. But why is that?
And thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Because in Xcode...magic happens :). Really i have no idea.But restarting Xcode....deleting derived data...and copying to new project(last solution to try) works more often than should.